# Firebase Cloud Messaging : we are unable to register the default service worker Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Hello i'm building a web chat application with Firebase Cloud messaging, my problem is that when i run the application on the computer that i'm building the app, it works fine and i am able to recieve a token. So i wanted to test if i can send messages to another computer and vice versa. so to do that i copied my project and sent it to another pc and ran the app there. But unlike on my own computer i get an error that says:

FireBaseError Messaging : We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ("https://localhost:44333/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope") with script ("https://localhost:44333/firebase-messaging-sw.js"): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed (messaging/failed_service-worker-registration).

I just dont understand why it works on my pc and not on any other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that firebase-messaging-sw.js had code errors (it said messaging.setBackgroundHandler is not a function) so i removed the error and it worked. But i still don't know why it worked fine in my own computer this way.